# Global matching using PCRE

Tags: c, regex, pcre

I try to match a comma-separated key-value pairs using PCRE. The text looks like this:

```
"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"
```

and the tested pattern is:

```
/(\s*)(,?)"([a-zA-Z0-9]+?)":(\s*)"([a-zA-Z0-9]+?)"/gm
```

The regex can be tested [here](https://regex101.com/r/BLiZMR/1):

It works in this test page but with this C code it displayes only the first matching group.

```
pcre *re;
pcre_extra *sd;
const char *error;
int rc, erroroffset, i;
int ovector[OVECCOUNT];
re = pcre_compile(pattern, 0, &error, &erroroffset, NULL);
sd = pcre_study(
    re,             /* result of pcre_compile() */
    0,              /* no options */
    &error);        /* set to NULL or points to a message */
rc = pcre_exec(   /* see below for details of pcre_exec() options */
    re, sd, json, 7, 0, 0, ovector, 30);
pcre_free_study(sd);
printf("Match succeeded at offset %d\n", ovector[0]);
for (i = 0; i < rc; i++) {
    char *substring_start = json + ovector[2*i];
    int substring_length = ovector[2*i+1] - ovector[2*i];
    printf("%2d: '%.*s'\n", i, substring_length, substring_start);
}
```

The result is

```
Match succeeded at offset 1
 0: '"key1": "value1"'
 1: ''
 2: ''
 3: 'key1'
 4: ' '
 5: 'value1'
```

but I need to have all matching groups, with

```
'key2'
'value2'
```

Comment: You've not shown the regex in the question — a link offsite is possibly useful auxilliary information, but not part of a question.  You also need to read up on how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name.  You've not shown the input data, but we shouldn't have to guess.

Comment: The update was helpful — thanks.  You should consider adding a `\s*` before the colon in the regex; JSON allows white space there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One execution of `pcre_exec()` will capture one key-value pair.  You have to repeat the `pcre_exec()` to get the extra key-value pairs.  Obviously, on the second iteration, you need to start at a different location in the string — the offset of the last matched character is available as `ovector[1]`, so you'd capture that and use:

```
size_t offset = 0;

while ((rc = pcre_exec(…, json + offset, …)) == 0)
{
    …
    offset += ovector[1];
}
```

You could also investigate [`pcre_dfa_exec()`](https://pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcreapi.html#SEC23).

I wonder why you capture the (optional) leading white space and comma as separate items — is that information beneficial?  It depends on your requirements, of course.